# CRM 2016 - How to create a parent-child relationship with multiple parent types?

Tags: dynamics-crm, parent-child, microsoft-dynamics

I have an entity - `EntityZ`, which has a `ParentId` where `ParentId` could be `EntityA.Id`, `EntityB.Id` or `EntityC.Id`. Is it possible to create this in MS Dynamics CRM 2016? If yes, how? I've looked but couldn't find a similar question or any help on the web.

Comment: Your edit portion will draw opinions not answers. Totally upto you how do you want to design your project & if that’s the requirement - options were given below as answers..

Comment: @ArunVinoth: Noted, will remove that, maybe that needs to go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

An entity can be the child party in only one full parental relationship. When you are looking for a way to cascade record ownership, deletion a.o. between mutiple parent - child entities you can create *configurable cascading* relationships.

As Arun Vinoth pointed out you can design your entity as an *activity* type. However, this may conflict with the semantics of activity records in CRM. Also, doing this would make it possible to associate the child entity to any entity that is enabled for activities.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a [trade off](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2014/12/05/crm-2013-when-should-you-create-a-custom-activity-entity) to achieve this. **Custom entity as Custom Activity**

Creating custom entity EntityZ as custom activity and EntityA, B, C can act as parent.

EntityA or B or C can be chosen as `RegardingObjectId` of EntityZ.

This has security limitation like EntityZ will be visible to everyone as this will be listed like other activities (Email, Phonecall, Task, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth nothing that Dynamics 365 does contain and out-of-box "polymorphic" customer field.

This field can link to either an Account or Contact:

[image]

And while it can be kludgy, another option would be to create 3 lookups and only populate one. Once one is populated you could hide the other two. Or, you could have a "Parent Type" option set to determine which lookup to show.

It would be a bit messy to show three lookups in a view, with only one populated, so you might also want a Parent Name text field in to which you could concatenate the type and name. You could use a workflow to populate it, and then use it in views and reports.